# :valid and :invalid selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In jQuery [3.2.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js), calling below expressions returns `"undefined"` (for both):

```
typeof $.expr[":"]["valid"]
typeof $.expr[":"]["invalid"]
```

However, it is possible to call `$(":valid")` or `$(":invalid")` and in the example below, it seems that these selectors return inputs that have valid or invalid value.
It is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that these selectors exist.

Please check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/cegy31bm/) for clarification.

- Can you explain where `:valid` and `:invalid` selectors are defined?
- How are these selectors resolved by jQuery?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with what `$.expr[":"]` is supposed to do, but to me it seems that by adding `["valid"]` you are trying to **access the property "valid"** of whatever-that-first-expression-returns. Also, your examples have unmatched braces at the end.

Comment: @Peter B: And the result of that would be the implementation of the :valid pseudo, assuming one exists. The premise of this question is that said implementation does not exist, to the asker's surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery does not contain its own implementation of the `:valid` and `:invalid` selectors. These selectors work in jQuery through the browser's native implementation of the standard via `document.querySelectorAll()`.

This also implies that `$(":valid")` and `$(":invalid")` will not work in browsers that don't support these selectors, such as Internet Explorer 8 (incidentally the only such browser that does implement `querySelectorAll()`) and older.

Answer (score 2):

`:valid` and `:invalid` are not a jquery selectors. It is a CSS3 selectors. It is defined in the CSS Selectors Level 3 spec as a “validity pseudo-selector”, meaning it is used to style interactive elements based on an evaluation of user input.

You can get more clarity from the following url.

[CSS Selector :invalid](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/invalid/)